# SQL Server : 1 million rows aggregated data solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, aggregate

We have data (>1mil rows) spread over 13 tables.

We have > 15 stored procedure (distributions) based on different columns (ex: region, year, etc) and a stored procedure for lots of aggregated data.

The tables have a unique key (`int`) that's used for INNER JOINS, clustered index on this ID and covering indexes on the columns that are used in the aggregated and distributions queries.

All these stored procedures run in @8 minutes, but I would need the result in under 1 minute.

A workaround that I am thinking of would be to store the results of the distributions and the aggregated data after the first run and then, just retrieve the data without any computations. This scenario would work just fine, but on the stored procedures (that are dynamic sp) we have filters and this makes this option a little cumbersome.

Do you have any suggestion on how would be best to approach this scenario?

Comment: First suggestion would be to show some code...  And existing indices... And perhaps the portions of the execution plan that are running slowest

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  This is a QA site, which means that you should try to format requests in a QA format.  This is extremely vague, and the best answer I can give is to take a class on DB development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have little need to extend this solution (with the exceptions of your current filters), then I would recommend that you stick with the pre-backed reporting tables.  Your system is relatively small in database terms and the response time appears acceptable for your need.

Try to create a series of report tables, ideally with each table covering multiple reports.  You will end up with each table holding a superset of columns (more than a single report needs), but this will give you the greatest ease in ongoing maintainability.  Use your reporting tool (SSRS?) alongside stored procs to manage the filtering with user selectable parameters

Answer (score 0):

This scenario sounds like a candidate for a SQL Server Analysis Services cube. SSAS allows you to aggregate data and perform rapid analysis on large volumes of data. Hope this helps.